# Google API Vision - Could not load the default credentials

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-vision

I am trying to use the google Vision API.
I did the following steps:

1. Enabled the Google Vision API
2. Created the service account id
3. Setted the enviorement varialbe 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' with the json path
4. downloaded the API with composer
5. wrote the following code:

   ```
   $vision = new VisionClient([
     'projectId' => $googleApiKey,
   ]);
   ```

   $image = $vision->image(file_get_contents($path), ['FACE_DETECTION']);
   $result = $vision->annotate($image);

When I lunch this code I obtain the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message 'Could not load the default credentials.
```

Somebody can help me to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score -1):

It's best if you use an absolute path when specifying. E.g. `/credentials/creds.json` is better than `./creds.json`. Try setting the path absolutely.

You may want to try starting from a known good configuration. The following could be helpful:

```
git clone https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/php-docs-samples
cd php-docs-samples/quickstart

php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

php composer.phar install
php quickstart.php
```

```

If the quickstart gives you an issue regarding the timezone, add the following to `quickstart.php` after the require statement:

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

If your path is incorrect, you should see the error:

```
Uncaught exception 'DomainException' with message 'Unable to read the credential file specified by...
```

After diagnosing with the quickstart sample, then you should figure out what's going on in your code.